# How can I load AVRO files from Cloud storage to a BigQuery dataset where each avro file is loaded as a table?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have over 100 Avro files in a Storage bucket that i would like to create tables for in a BigQuery dataset i.e. one table per avro file.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#loading_avro_data_into_a_new_table) doesn't clarify how you can do this so I thought i would write a bash script but I am not having much luck.

The BQ table name for each avro file can be obtained from part of the avro file's name hence the use of grep.

Once all the BQ tables are created, I then wanted to load the relevant storage object into the relevant table.

However, it is not working - any ideas would be much appreciated...

```
#!/bin/bash

Project_Id=<project_id>
Dataset=<dataset_name>
Bucket=gs://<bucket_name>


#Make BigQuery tables from AVRO file names - for all objects in the specified bucket a BQ table needs to be created and named using a specific portion of the object name.

for object_to_table_name in $(gsutil ls ${Bucket} | grep -o -P '(?<=STARTOFOBJECTNAME).*(?=.avro)')
    do
        bq mk 
        --table
        ${Project_Id}:${Dataset}.${object_to_table_name}

#Load AVRO files into BigQuery tables

    for table_name in $(bq ls ${Dataset} | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>2')
        do
            bq load 
            --source_format=AVRO
            ${Project_Id}.${Dataset}.${table_name}
            ${Bucket}/${Dataset}.${table_name}.avro
        done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`bq load` automatically creates a table for you when loading from a file. Why not remove the part where you create a table using `bq mk` before loading using `bq load`? Just directly load the file. This code works for me:

```bash
Project_Id="your-project-id"
Dataset="your-dataset"
Bucket="gs://your-bucket"

for object_to_table_name in $(gsutil ls ${Bucket} | rev | cut -f 1 -d/ | rev | cut -f 1 -d\.)
    do
        full_path="${Project_Id}:${Dataset}.${object_to_table_name}"
        gcs_path="${Bucket}/${object_to_table_name}.avro"

        bq load --source_format=AVRO ${full_path} ${gcs_path}

done
```

Output:

[image]

Files in my bucket:

[image]

Created tables:

[image]